# Comparing and allocating elements in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have sorted (by a date not shown here) a list of numbers:

```
5, 7, 10, 4, 3, 7, 4
```

I want to get average of increases, so 5 to 7 and then 7 to 10 and 3 to 7 is (2+3+5)/3
I also want the average of decreases 10 to 4, 4 to 3 and 7 to 4 is (6+1+3)/3

Is there a simple way to do this in Linq?

Comment: Assuming the numbers are already sorted and are in a certain sequence. The logic is to take an average of the times the sequence when up separate from the number of times the sequence numbers went down (second paragraph in question has the example).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would calculate changes between two consecutive numbers first. That can be done with [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of same list by skipping first item. Then you can get changes which are moving up or changes which are moving down and calculate their average:

```
var changes = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (x,y) => y-x); // [ 2, 3, -6, -1, 4, -3 ]
var averageUp = changes.Where(x => x > 0).Average(); // 3
var averageDown = changes.Where(x => x < 0).Average(); // -3.33
```

Comment: Really smart solution!

Comment: I didn't know Zip existed. Thanks!

Comment: Zipping a collection with its tail, I see you're into functional programming :)